# Create a snapshot with name in AWS using Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, boto3, snapshot

I am able to create a snapshot using python and boto3 in my ec2 but i cant find a way to add a name to the created snapshot. I am using this code from the documentation to create a snapshot. How can I add a name to the created snapshot like when we manually create a snapshot for a volume?

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name = 'eu-central-1')


snapshot = ec2.create_snapshot(
    Description='Aws test snapshot',
    VolumeId='vol-0e3a3275b2b669g67',
    TagSpecifications=[
        {
            'ResourceType': 'snapshot',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'sony',
                    'Value': 'Test by sony'
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
    DryRun=False
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is just a tag name that is shown by default in the main view on the console. Similarly, you can choose to show other tags in that view too.

[image]

Having said that, your `Tags` section should look like this:

```
'Tags': [
    {
        'Key': 'sony',
        'Value': 'Test by sony'
    },
    {
        'Key': 'Name',
        'Value': 'My snapshot name'
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The field name is only the UI console thing for the snapshots. You can use the Description tag to identify the snapshots via code.

I know it is a bit annoying but that is how the snapshots are being created.. Also on the console thing it does not provide the option to give name while creating snapshot. It has to be done manually after the snapshot is done.

But still the last way to check this through is raise a ticket to aws support and they can confirm or deny if it is possible to do via program.